# How do you change the default home page in the Ubuntu Web Browser?

Tags: default-browser

How do you change the default home page in the Ubuntu Web Browser? Or Unity Browser.... The one that is now bundled with the OS in prep for the touch edition.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using that? Assuming you're talking about `webbrowser-app`